# How to keep time in Spring Data JPA

Tags: database, spring, spring-data-jpa

How to keep time (without date) in Spring Data JPA? Now I keep it in String. For example: "10:45". But in this way I can't return values between time like:
repository.findTimeBetween(String startTime, String endTime)

Comment: Are you looking to only use String or are you able to use something else like LocalTime or Unix timestamp or etc?

Comment: I use jHipster and it doesn't allow LocalTime. But I think that I can use it manually. https://jhipster.github.io/jdl/

Comment: Patres: Which version of Java you are using ? or else do you have any restrictions to use joda time library ? have a look at my example

Comment: I use Java 8, yes I saw your example. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the time as a String in the database, you can't use it for comparisons, rather you need to store the time value as a numeric type.

**Using Java8:**

Use `java.time.LocalTime` API and store the Time value as an `integer` (big int) type in the database. Then, you can use the `repository. findByStartDateBetween(time1,time2)`.

The below two API methods of `LocalTime` are hepful for conversions from long to LocalTime and String to LocalTime objects.

> static LocalTime  ofSecondOfDay(long secondOfDay)

Obtains an instance of LocalTime from a second-of-day value.

> static LocalTime  parse(CharSequence text)

Obtains an instance of LocalTime from a text string such as 10:15.

You can refer the API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)

**Without using Java8:**

If you are not using Java8, you can use Joda time library for this.

You can refer [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html)

Comment: I don't know if I understand. Do You suggest keep it in Integer like this:     @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalTime  startTime;

And when I need Time I should pare to LocalTime?

Comment: Declare as: @Column(name = "start_time") private long startTime;

Comment: When you need time back, you need to get it by: LocalTime locatime = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(startTime);  Refer the API in the above Java8 link.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand