# Spring - LocalDateTime - how to return just the hours and minutes instead of dd-mm-yyyy hh-MM-ss-sss

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, localdatetime

I have a column called starttime in my 'workout' table in my DB, I am trying to use LocalDateTime to save the start time to that column. In my workout class, I have entered the following:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="HH:mm")
@Column(name = "starttime")
private LocalDateTime startTime;
```

I am then trying to save a testWorkout in my dataloader as follows:

```
Workout testWorkout = new Workout(LocalDateTime.now(), 88.00);
workoutRepository.save(testWorkout);
```

when I run my application and check in postgresql / postico, I see the start time as:
2022-02-01 12:53:26.488

How do I get it to just log hours and minutes?

I am fairly new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Column(name = "local_time", columnDefinition = "TIME")
private LocalTime localTime;             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368585/how-to-keep-time-in-spring-data-jpa

Comment: you can use this syntax: localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"))

Comment: LocalDateTime having method getHour() and getMinute()

if it fits in your requirement plz use it.

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions. I got it working with the following:
``` @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
    @JsonProperty("starttime")
    @Column(name = "starttime", columnDefinition = "TIME")
    private LocalTime startTime;```

Answer (score 2):

There is a special class for this: [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). Also to see proper way to do so look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934496/jackson-deserialize-date-from-twitter-to-zoneddatetime) (although there they show the example with ZonedDateTime)

Comment: thats awesome! thank you for that. I got it working with the following code:
``` @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
    @JsonProperty("starttime")
    @Column(name = "starttime", columnDefinition = "TIME")
    private LocalTime startTime;```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

```
Table 8.14. Date/Time Output Styles
Style Specification     Description     Example
ISO       ISO 8601, SQL standard      1997-12-17 07:37:16-08
SQL       traditional style           12/17/1997 07:37:16.00 PST
Postgres    original style        Wed Dec 17 07:37:16 1997 PST
German       regional style               17.12.1997 07:37:16.00 PST
```

from this chart,which means, database query output can not return time as "HH-MM".
So you need to format it to char/text type.
24 hour type:

```
select to_char(localtime(0),'HH24:MI');
```

12 hour type

```
 select to_char(localtime(0),'HH12:MI');
```